# CMB2 metabox conditional logic

Tags: metabox, plugins

I am using [CMB2](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2) for metabox on custom posts. I am adding a metabox by using code below:

```
$cmb_demo->add_field( array(
    'name'       => __( 'Test Text', 'cmb2' ),
    'desc'       => __( 'field description (optional)', 'cmb2' ),
    'id'         => $prefix . 'text',
    'type'       => 'text',
    'show_on_cb' => 'show_this_field_if_true', 
) );
```

I understand show_this_field_if_true will be a function that will return true or false. But, I want to make this as conditional with another field. This field will show if another field's value is true.

Here is an example that Don't show this field if it's not the front page template

```
function show_this_field_if_true( $cmb ) {
    if ( $cmb->object_id !== get_option( 'page_on_front' ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

How can I make this conditional with a field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is by using JavaScript and there is a couple of CMB2 plugins let you do that easily:

1. [CMB2 Conditional](https://github.com/jcchavezs/cmb2-conditionals)
2. [CMB2 Conditional Logic](https://github.com/awran5/CMB2-conditional-logic)

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace the `get_option` call with a call to `get_post_meta`:

```
function show_this_field_if_true( $cmb ) {
    // Check if other meta value exists
    if ( ! get_post_meta( $cmb->object_id, 'other_meta_key_to_check', 1 ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Keep in mind, this will only work for the initial page-load and will not show the field until you update the `other_meta_key_to_check` value and save the page.

Comment: It should be possible to use ajax to save the fields that are supposed to trigger a field box to show or hide, and reload the meta values, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, it's certainly possible, but since there are so many different field types, it's not simple to document the process.